# How to authenticate protect a backend web api for server to server communication using Azure Ad client_credentials

Tags: azure, curl, asp.net-web-api, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have a curl script which requests a new access token from Azure AD. I need it to return a claim of some kind for my API, either a role or a scope either will work.

I can get an access token however its not returning a role claim or a scope or anything of that nature.

When used in the web API

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                 
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

I get:

> Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token.

I did try setting

```
"AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL" : true,
```

In [appsettings.json](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis#verification-of-scopes-or-app-roles-in-the-controller-actions) but it did not stop the error from coming as it was supposed to do.

This is being used to authorize between a curl script and a microservice.  As its a background service there is **no user** interaction its just server to server authorization.  I am simply trying to protect the web api. So for security reasons I want to be sure that the access token created is in fact an access token for this system that's why im looking for some kind of claim or role on my application to ensure that its not just a random access token from another part of the system.

Without a role or a scope my application is throwing the following error

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token.

Oauth2 uses scopes to enable a user to grant a client access to their data as this does not require that I don't think what I am looking for her is scopes.   I think what I need is a way to define a role for the application itself.  I have very little experience with azure so please correct me if i'm wrong.

## curl script

> curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee&client_secret=[secret]&resource=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee" https://login.microsoftonline.com/1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d65bb83b5/oauth2/token

## Response

```
    {
      "aud": "api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abee",
      "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d6583b5/",
      "iat": 1628506854,
      "nbf": 1628506854,
      "exp": 1628510754,
      "aio": "E2ZgYChZ8/PRc/eJ5sYfulfVXWUrBQA=",
      "appid": "a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee",
      "appidacr": "1",
      "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d65bb835/",
      "oid": "81f74198-ab14-4b0b-bad6-62893e15f9c8",
      "rh": "0.AQsA1tYqHk8n6EOJ79NtZbuDtTFKmaSUxHNLliLTpxRKvu4AAA.",
      "sub": "81f74198-ab14-4b0b-bad6-62893e15f9c",
      "tid": "1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d65bb83b",
      "uti": "FaZGzuuRn0eEQYPRReoYAQ",
      "ver": "1.0"
    }
```

I tried setting up a scope

[image]

and then adding it to the curl script

> curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee&client_secret=[Secret]&resource=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee&scope=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee/load_scope" https://login.microsoftonline.com/1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d65bb83b5/oauth2/token

There was no effect at all the access token still does not contain any scopes.

Then i tried adding a role

[image]

add adding the role to the resource

> curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee&client_secret=[secret]&resource=api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee/load" https://login.microsoftonline.com/1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d65bb83b5/oauth2/token

but that just returns an error

> {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://a4994a31-c494-4b73-9622-d3a7144abeee/load was not found in the tenant named 1e2ad6d6-274f-43e8-89ef-d36d65bb83b5. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

## manifest

I am currently following  [Assign app roles to applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-app-roles-to-applications) This is the manifest.

```
"appId": "51bdea30-a886-47f7-a27f-994c8caca5c",
    "appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "myapprole",
            "displayName": "myapprole",
            "id": "bdaa8bc7-e0b3-47b1-b92-9011313e16ae",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "myapprole"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Did you tried  adding custom claim configuration `Add optional claim`? You can get it  `Your application => Token configuration => Add optional claim`

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to add a custom claim they all seem to be assocated with user login (name, email ....)  This is an app requesting access not a user.

Comment: Could you please go through this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles)

Comment: Actually i am following this section in that same page [Assign app roles to applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-app-roles-to-applications) as this is for a backend service not intended for users.   I did try the users one as well but as again its not a user logging in there was no change.

Comment: If you need users claims then I think `client_credentials` wouldn't be the best choice, because it for application, but you need to use `authorization code` flow in this case.

Comment: I don't need users claims, there is no user.   authorization code flow is used for Oauth2 for a user to grant access.    I have no user.   Thats why i am using client_credentials grant type.   I just need two backend service to be authorized to talk to each other.   So that i don't get a third service that tries to talk but isn't allowed to.  Hence the idea of using roles instead.

Comment: I don't think you could get required claim using `client_credentials`. So you create api and expose that to your 3rd party consumer.

Comment: According to the documentation you should be able to get a role claim for applications using client_credentials.

Comment: Since you havevn't assign any user to that application not sure this might cause that you are not getting claim.

Comment: You understand what a backend microservice is correct? They don't have users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to add `AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL` this removes the error message and allows to backend services to communicate without the need for roles or claims.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token.

I had added it but it wasnt working after digging around in the source code for Microsoft.Identity.Web.  I found that I was on an older version of
[Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/6b506ebb241b69dd79975b5899418af825dc1882/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiExtensions/MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L235) which was apparently prior to the addition of the `AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL` check. I deleted the NuGet Package and readded it at 1.15.2 and it works.

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Redacted]",
    "ClientId": "[Redacted]",
    "TenantId": "[Redacted]",
    "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL" : true,
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```